# How to add number options to notification badges in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'd like to implement notification numbered badges similar to what WhatsApp/Twitter has done. In the default notification settings for badges in Android, you often have the options to show a "Dot" or "Don't show," but I'm interested in having a number displayed on the badge. WhatsApp/Twitter has successfully implemented this feature.

Here's an example screenshot of what I'm referring to:
[image]

What would be the recommended approach to create such numbered badge notifications.

I tried this library "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar" but didn't worked for me.